# What's the correct way to find out if a Windows Server 2003 SP 1 is a 32 bit or a 64 bit?

Tags: c++, c, architecture, 32bit-64bit

I was looking for a way to determine the above. I could not really find it easily and google somehow couldn't help me much with it too.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you whant to find it a compile time or runtime ?

Comment: It's a VM that i am using, should be some easier way right?

Comment: GO-  "my Computer"-right click-> properties and you will see the version

Comment: @thumbmunkeys FORTRAN...wont compile on c

Comment: @apomene that doesn't work...

Comment: @MitchWheat I am sure no one has asked for Windows Server 2003 SP 1, so enjoy your meal :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Mitch found the dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [GetNativeSystemInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API Call. The information you are looking for will be returned in the `SYSTEM_INFO` structure in the `wProcessorArchitecture` member.

Comment: No, it is emulated thoroughly.  Only GetNativeSystemInfo() speaks the truth.